# Eclipse - Ouline View - Turn Off Filtering

Tags: eclipse

I recently installed Eclipse on my new computer, and this installation somewhat filters the class members. I think it is somehow related to the Outline, but i couldn't find any settings related to it.

The thing is that when i, for example, have an error in a method, and click on the little red square on the margin, eclipse shows me **only** that method, and nothing else. When i then click on the class name in the outline panel, eclipse shows me the class without import declarations. I can, of course, click on the import declarations in the outline panel, but then i get only them. When I want to jump to the declaration of some method by command-clicking that method's name, I again get only that method on the screen. It is really annoying.

Can anyone please help me fix it?

Best regards,
Timofey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try that (On Windows OS):

```
Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor
```

Remove at that window the "Only show the selected Java element" option.

Comment: Yup, that was that. Thank you very much. Kind of embarrassing.

Comment: This is also useful to do the opposite, to turn on the filter.

Answer (score 0):

Everything works here... Is there anyway you can reproduce this with a blank/ fresh installation of eclipse? Which version of eclipse? Which package?

Or maybe you turn on the option `Only show the selected Java element` in the editor preferences?